# set do "" empty jaxb fields/attributes

Tags: jaxb

I have an xsd saying that some elements/attributes are required, anyway server side I can send some "empty" fields, for example:

```
<myEmptyField attr1="" attr2=""/>
```

how can I obtain this behaviour with jaxb?

Answer (score 0):

You can achieve what you are looking for **elements** as shown below. There are [2 other alternatives for specifying the absence of data](http://jaxb.java.net/tutorial/section_2_2_13-Defining-Subtypes.html).

```
@XmlElement(name = "myEmptyField", required = true)
```

For **attributes**, I thought we can use as shown below, but it isn't working (I need to check why) but an alternative is to set the value on the POJO to empty string.

```
@XmlAttribute(name = "attr1", required = true)
```

Comment: @user1610075 then post your pojo and marshalling code and output.